# Appstore and add more markets

Tags: iphone, app-store

I've already published an app on Appstore, limited to some markets.
Is it possibile to add more markets just changing some data on itunesconnect ? 
Or maybe do I have to update the app?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change markets: Go to http://itunesconnect.apple.com then 'Manage your apps' --> Choose your app --> 'Rights and Pricing' (blue button)